# Write CFArray to disk

Tags: ios4

I have CFArray full of many CF bits and bobs. I need to write this to the file system for retrieval later. One way to do this would be to run through the array and recast the contents to their NSCoding compliant counterparts, but this would take quite some time, and I don't really need to do anything with the data other than save it.

Is there a way to write out the CFArray to a file that does not require the above?

Cheers,

Rich

Answer (score 0):

No — there's no free lunch here; to serialize an array, you have to be able to write out everything that's in it, and that means that everything has to implement NSCoding.